# Inline style to act as :hover in CSS

Tags: html, css

I know that embedding CSS styles directly into the HTML tags they affect defeats much of the purpose of CSS, but sometimes it's useful for debugging purposes, as in:

```
<p style="font-size: 24px">asdf</p>
```

What's the syntax for embedding a rule like:

```
a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
```

into the style attribute of an A tag? It's obviously not this...

```
<a href="foo" style="text-decoration: underline">bar</a>
```

...since that would apply all the time, as opposed to just during hover.

Comment: Theoretically, if you are trying to make the hover something dynamic, you could use javascript to inject a hover rule into a stylesheet using the window.document.styleSheets list of existing sheets.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293280/css-pseudo-classes-with-inline-styles

Answer (score 126, accepted):

I'm afraid it can't be done, the pseudo-class selectors can't be set in-line, you'll have to do it on the page or on a stylesheet.

I should mention that *technically* you *should* be able to do it [according to the CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr#cascading), but most browsers don't support it

**Edit:** I just did a quick test with this:

```
<a href="test.html" style="{color: blue; background: white} 
            :visited {color: green}
            :hover {background: yellow}
            :visited:hover {color: purple}">Test</a>
```

And it doesn't work in IE7, IE8 beta 2, Firefox or Chrome.  Can anyone else test in any other browsers?

Comment: That's a very low priority CSS 3 working draft that hasn't been updated in six years.  From the spec: 'It is inappropriate to use W3C Working Drafts as reference material or to cite them as other than "work in progress." '

Comment: True, but browsers do implement some CSS3 rules, *should* is probably the wrong word in this context

Comment: Browsers typically implement CSS features that are in a further development state, e.g. opacity is from CSS Color (Last Call) and Media Queries is a Candidate Recommendation.

Comment: Wouldn't style=":hover {}" be equivalent to "a { :hover {} }" in stylesheet? That obviously is a syntax error.

Comment: This answer was posted very long time ago, things have changed since that and the current version of the relevant W3C spec — CSS Style Attribute Rec. (http://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/#syntax) — clearly says that style attribute can contain only the contents of a CSS declaration block. So it's now impossible to insert pseudo elements with `style` attribute.

Comment: I just needed this for a fast fix, and it worked in Chrome  93.0.4577.82.
I added sth like this to a link tag: 

`<a href="" style="text-decoration:underline; :hover {text-decoration:none};">test</a>`

Even though inline style should be avoided, sometimes a fast fix if helpful. :) 
Thanx for the hint!

Comment: Oh! 5 mins to edit a comment? Final version: 

Just needed this for a fast fix & it worked in Chrome 93.0.4577.82.
I added sth. like this to a link tag: 

`<a href="" style="text-decoration:underline; :hover {text-decoration:none}">test</a>`

Important notice: it didn't work putting a ; after the } 
So this didn't work: 
`<a href="" style="text-decoration:underline; :hover {text-decoration:none};">test</a>`
neither this:
`<a href="" style=":hover {text-decoration:none};">test</a>`

Even though inline style should be avoided, sometimes a fast fix is helpful. :) 
Thanx 4 the hint!

Answer (score 37):

If you are only debugging, you might use javascript to modify the css:

```
<a onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline';" 
    onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none';">bar</a>
```

Comment: Searched for a solution with JSF and this helped me to fix it. onmousemove="this.style.color='##{cc.attrs.color}';"
onmouseout="this.style.color='white';"

Comment: Thanks! That's worked for me :)

Comment: Another way is to use pointer events, it's better for different devices, and we can change the whole style attribute too: `<div style="color: green; background: gray" onpointerenter="this.setAttribute('style', 'color: blue; background: red')" onpointerleave="this.setAttribute('style', 'color: red; background: blue')">some content</div>`

Answer (score 30):

A simple solution:

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="this.style.color='orange';" onmouseout="this.style.color='';">My Link</a>
```

Or

```
<script>
 /** Change the style **/
 function overStyle(object){
    object.style.color = 'orange';
    // Change some other properties ...
 }

 /** Restores the style **/
 function outStyle(object){
    object.style.color = 'orange';
    // Restore the rest ...
 }
</script>

<a href="#" onmouseover="overStyle(this)" onmouseout="outStyle(this)">My Link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked in Blogger for an image.

Answer (score 18):

If it's for debugging, just add a css class for hovering (since elements can have more than one class):

```
a.hovertest:hover
{
text-decoration:underline;
}

<a href="http://example.com" class="foo bar hovertest">blah</a>
```

Comment: This is probably the closest you're going to get to the desired effect

Answer (score 1):

I put together a quick solution for anyone wanting to create hover popups without CSS using the onmouseover and onmouseout behaviors.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lk9w1mkv/

```
<div style="position:relative;width:100px;background:#ddffdd;overflow:hidden;" onmouseover="this.style.overflow='';" onmouseout="this.style.overflow='hidden';">first hover<div style="width:100px;position:absolute;top:5px;left:110px;background:white;border:1px solid gray;">stuff inside</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If that `<p>` tag is created from JavaScript, then you do have another option: use JSS to programmatically insert stylesheets into the document head. It does support `'&:hover'`. https://cssinjs.org/