# Using :hover for an element's inline style (using HTML/CSS/php)

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, hover

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do I embed an “a:hover{…}” rule into a style attribute in the middle of a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131653/how-do-i-embed-an-ahover-rule-into-a-style-attribute-in-the-middle-of-a-d)
>   [How to write a:hover in inline CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css)

I want to dynamically change the hover colour of an element, but not using external CSS stylesheets, only inline.  This is the code (using php to generate the element)

```
echo '
<div class="container" style="color:#'.$color.'">
  '.$contents.'
</div>';
```

When the user hovers over this container element, the color style will change to the value of `$color` (at the moment there is no hovering).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css

Comment: This is a repost of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css

The cliff notes are that `:hover` is a pseudo class and can really only be used within a stylesheet.

You can create a class and assign it via PHP or use some JS to do `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`.

Comment: You can do it using javascipt. is javascript appreciable ?

Comment: Yes, I suppose Javascript can do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will help you if javascript is appreciable

```
<TD onMouseOver="this.bgColor='#00CC00'" onMouseOut="this.bgColor='#009900'" bgColor=#009900>
<A HREF="http://www.mysite.com">Click Here</A></TD>
```

or

Javascript Change Hyperlink Text Color Onmouseover

```
<style type="text/css">

a {
font-weight:bold;
font-family:verdana;
text-decoration:none;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function changeColor(idObj,colorObj)
{
    document.getElementById(idObj.id).style.color = colorObj;
}
</script>
```

```
<a href="#" style="color: #000000" onmouseover="this.style.color='#FF0000'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#000000'">
    Link 1</a>
<br />
<br />
<a href="#" style="color: #999999" onmouseover="this.style.color='#008000'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#999999'">
    Link 2</a>
<br />
<br />
<a href="#" style="color: #FF0000" onmouseover="this.style.color='blue'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#FF0000'">
    Link 3</a>
<br />
<br />
<a id="lnk1" href="#" style="color: #008000" onmouseover="changeColor(this,'#FF0000');"
    onmouseout="changeColor(this,'#008000');">Link Color change using javascript function</a>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById(idObj.id).style.color = colorObj;` could also be done like this: `idObj.style.color = colorObj;`because you already have the object (this) so why not directly set it there without get it again with the document. - anyway: +1 because it was the right solution for a dynamic hover styling ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can't, since you can't set the pseudo-selectors inline. Ideally, you should design separate classes in your external css which would represent the various hover states you need, and in PHP assign these classes to your content.