# Adding d3 svg.selectAll(".foo").style("fill",...) overrides .foo:hover css rule

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg, d3.js

I am making a d3 choropleth that assigns initial `fill` property values according to a colorization algorithm to the tune of:

```
  svg.selectAll(".foo")
      .style("fill", function(d){ 
        return colorization(getRandomArbitrary(5,25)); //returns hex value
      })
```

This works. Unfortunately, it seems to render my CSS rule irrelevant. The rule works without making the call to `.style()` via d3:

```
  .foo:hover{
    fill: white;
  }
```

I'm not sure if this is something that d3.js is doing, or a result of some sort of interplay between SVG styles and CSS styles.

I am looking for a solution that accomplishes the algorithmic colorization and continues to permit the :hover fill effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expected behavior of CSS and is not unique to SVG or D3. Inline styles override `:hover` styles. You can override it using `!important`.

```
.foo:hover {
    fill: white !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This was sloppy on my part. I didn't realize that .style() appended the style inline, though in retrospect it is obvious.

Answer (score 3):

@Alexander O'Mara 's answer is excellent, however, since you said you are '...looking for a solution that accomplishes the algorithmic colorization...', I just want to bring to your attention another, different, approach.

You can explicitly, programmaticaly, set hover effect with these lines:

```
svg.selectAll(".foo")
    .style("fill", function(d){ 
        return colorization(getRandomArbitrary(5,25)); //returns hex value
    })
    .on("mouseover", function() { d3.select(this).style("fill", "white") } )
    .on("mouseout", function() { function(d){ 
        return colorization(getRandomArbitrary(5,25));
    })
```

That way you don't need anything in css file - so there is nothing to be 'overwritten'. :)

Unfortunately, one can't directly convert ":hover" styles from css to inline styles - event handlers must be used, like in the code above!

This is inspired by the solution of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078469/transferring-all-css-statements-to-d3-chains-in-javascript-trouble-with-hover).