# Is there a way to change css on hover with (style="")?

Tags: html, css

I know you can import a css file that contains, let's say:

```
div {
    color: black; 
}

div:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

but is there a way to get the same effect but in the html?

So something with

```
<div style="color: black;"></div>
```

I KNOW you can do it with js, but I just wanted to know if there were a hack for it.. And no the "duplicate" question did not contain the answer I was looking for, keep in mind that was 4 years ago.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131653/how-do-i-embed-an-ahover-rule-into-a-style-attribute-in-the-middle-of-a

Comment: There was no answer there... this is 4 years later and it might be able now we have html5 and css3

Comment: @OussamaDooby +1 for the thought, but researching a little bit would have helped to not open another duplicate question.

Comment: There just might be someone out(here/there) who has a little hack for it... We all know css is FULL of hacks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pseudo classes are not allowed to use as inline CSS, so the short answer is NO, you cannot do what you are trying to achieve.

Consider using `<style>` tags at document level, or you can use JavaScript if you want to..

```
<a href="#" onmouseover = "this.style.color = '#000'" 
            onmouseout  = "this.style.color = '#f00'">Hi</a>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rNWX7/)

And as you commented, still the answer is no, even using HTML5/CSS3 there's no way you can use pseudo classes inline.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div onmouseover="this.style.color='black'">I wouldn't suggest this</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way as far I know. But you can still realize it with js.

```
<div
   onmouseover="this.style.color='#ff0000'"
   onmouseout="this.style.color='#000000'">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
<div style=":hover {color: red}">Testing inline hover</div>
```

Comment: Write on comment please

Comment: <div style=":hover {color: red}">Testing inline hover</div>

Comment: @AldiUnanto I don't think he has commenting rights

Comment: Don't understand the -1 I was refering to the link provided in the first answer. That possibility appear ins W3C
http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css-style-attr-20020515
It doesn't work on browsers but it's there

Comment: The same answer I gave was given in the original question and got 7 positive votes.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css#comment9295011_1033166
In the questions says he knows it can be done with js, and the solutions given are in javascript...