# Why an inline style for an element cancels a `:hover` for the same?

Tags: html, css, hover, inline-styles

I know if I set an inline style for example for the `color`, it cancels style about color in the style tag or a CSS file (to reason the priority order). But why does it cancel setting a color for `:hover` for the same element?
While it is for the `hover` case and not for a normal color.

```css
a {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="/" style="color: tomato">Home</a>
```

And how to fix that? Only with this answer? (Setting `:hover` in anchor tag?)

[Inline style to act as :hover in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131653/inline-style-to-act-as-hover-in-css)

Thanks for guids:)

Comment: I think the problem is that you set `color` to `tomato` in the `style` attribute *and* set it to `white` in the CSS. If you remove the `style` attribute, does it work as intended?

Comment: pseudo-classes have the same specificity as class selectors. You could increase the specificity on `:hover` selector, or use `!important`.

Comment: @cSharp Thanks, it is an appropriate answer for me.

Comment: @Julia Yes, you're right. But I want to fix it while there is an inline styling. It only was a challenge:) thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right the but if need to make the color change while hovering the text you must do like this(just Added The Important Tag):

```css
a {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

a:hover {
  color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<a href="/" style="color: tomato">Home</a>
```

Comment: `!important` is generally [more trouble than it is worth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9245360/19068). It can solve a problem *once* but then, if your CSS gets more complex and you get another instance of the same problem, you can't double `!important`.

Comment: but if you look that inline styles is not a good way to apply Css that make a sense if your applying style inline you are using important tag ot overruled the inline css

Comment: @Quentin Yes, you're right. Although I was looking for a solution to use `:hover`  while there is an inline styling.

Answer (score 1):

> But why does it cancel setting a color for :hover for the same element?

See [specificity in the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity).

A style attribute is more specific that any combination of selectors.

> And how to fix that?

Avoid style attributes. Use a class and write a ruleset that targets it instead.

```css
a {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

a.foo {
  color: tomato
}

a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="/" class="foo">Home</a>
```